# Definition for Day Angle

Tags: declination

I am searching for a *proper definition* for day angle.
The day angle  $\Gamma$ is calculated as follows:$$\Gamma = 2\pi\cdot \frac{n_{day} - 1}{365}$$

Comment: Some context and the source might help.  But it looks like what Kepler calls the "mean annomoly".

Answer (score 1):

Since a solar year, i.e. the time over which the Earth completes an orbit about the Sun, is about 365.24 days, I would change 365 to a more precise value of 365.24

Then the quantity $n\equiv2\pi/365.24$ will be the so-called *mean motion* of the Earth, i.e., the mean orbital angular velocity.

Multiplying it by the number of day, we obtain a discretised version of the *mean anomaly*, as Greg Miller rightly pointed out in his comment above.

Whether you wish to define your $\Gamma$ as $n\,(n_{day} -1)$ or as $n\,n_{day} $ is a matter of choice. In the former case, your $\Gamma$ will be the mean anomaly value in the beginning of the day number $n_{day}$. In the latter case, in the end of this day. For example, in [this lecture course](https://hal-mines-paristech.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01676634v1/preview/2018_basics_solaire_wald_v1.pdf) the author preferred the latter option -- but then, again, it was a matter of his choice.